# jquery how to unload or hide javascript?

Tags: jquery

i have a jquery script. see fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/patrioticcow/vLzCU/5/), that loads some scripts depending on what option i select.

there are a few problems.

1. I cant make the js unload/hide when the other option is selected (what if i have more options?)
2. and the script doesnt load inside `#feed-1307038796890991` but next to it.. wired

any help much appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: It seems like the code in fiddler is working correctly. It loads the script properly. I think that there is something in the response that is doing all the work. To give a proper answer, could we see this too?

Comment: Why are you using 1 element arrays?

Comment: My advice would be not to use this "bloople" thing. Just parse the RSS feeds yourself. They're not that complicated.

Comment: Oh wait, that'd be an XSS problem. Are the RSS feeds hosted on the same site, or are they someone elses?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a better attempt:

http://jsfiddle.net/Eric/vLzCU/7/

I really can't see what was going through your head when you wrote the code. Why are there two single element arrays? And why are you using a variable to index them?

Comment: those scripts are different each time the user selects an option

Comment: @Patrioticcow: I'm not sure what you're trying to say.

Comment: it is like i have 3 scripts and they are connected to those option from that list. in my fiddle example u can see that. the only problem there is that if there is a script already loaded, if i select another option the script that is already loaded doesn't disappear. to if i load 10 scripts they will all be loaded into the page. What i want is to load a script and unload/hide the others